# Lifting locally nilpotent representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let G be a semi-simple affine algebraic group over a field of characteristic $0$. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be its lie algebra with standard decomposition $\mathfrak{g}= \mathfrak{n}^{-} \oplus \mathfrak{h} \oplus \mathfrak{n}^{+}$.

Given a locally nilpotent $\mathfrak{n}^{+}$ representation, how can one lift to a representation of a unipotent group $N$, where Lie$(N)=\mathfrak{n^+}$ ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N$ be a unipotent group such that $Lie(N) = \mathfrak{n}$. WLOG we can assume that we have been given an embedding of $N$ in $GL(m)$ and consequently an embedding of $\mathfrak{n}$ in $\mathfrak{gl}(m)$. Also we can with $\mathbb{C}-$points and it will be clear from the construction of the representation that it(representation) is defined over the base field. Since $\mathfrak{n}$ is a nilpotent lie algebra we get that $exp : \mathfrak{n} \rightarrow N$ is surjective. Hence it is enough to define elements of the form $exp(x), x \in \mathfrak{n}$.

Note that $exp(x).v$ for $v \in V$ makes sense as the module $V$ is locally nilpotent. Here we are using the fact that exponential map is given by the usual exponential map applied to matrices. Also since exponential only involves rational coefficients, hence the representation is defined over the base field.